# is there an “app store” for regular pc apps?

Tags: licensing, sales, app

I have written an app for the computer in java, but i don't want to give it out for free. I only want to charge somewhere between $0.99 - $2.99, is there a website that i can upload it to, to do this for me. I am looking for something like the apple app store, or the android market, but for the computer. Does this exist? also, is there a way to control the amount of computers it can be installed on? ie. if a person is using a specific key, they can only use the program one one computer at a time, like i-tunes movies. the program is a standalone app, meaning there is no installation process, you just open the executable file and it works. will this be a problem for integrating a licensing function.

Comment: This would be better asked in two questions, since the licensing question is very different from the app store question.  You could search for licensing in the search box, since I think we had a question about licensing software just a little while ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu has a closed-source applications app-store, so that covers one option for linux:
[techie-buzz article on ubuntu app store](http://techie-buzz.com/foss/ubuntu-official-app-store.html)

There is also intel's [App-up](http://www.appup.com/applications/index) for netbook apps

Microsoft has plans for an apple-style app-store of their own, but as far as i know they're not rolling it out yet.

Answer (score 3):

There are many, many services which will process the sale for you and send you a check, and they've been around since the earliest days of the web.  Though they're usually called 'shareware registration services' or somesuch, rather than the more faddish 'app store'.

If you are looking for something more integrated, like a phone app store, several are in the works.  Embarcadero, for example, has announced [AppWave](http://signup.appwavestore.com/), which allows buyers to download and run applications within a sandboxed environment, isolating applications from each other.  I think even Apple was talking about a PC variant of their store.